# AWS ECS Cluster - Why does Task Definitions need Memory and CPU and Volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs

Why does Task Definitions need Memory and CPU and Volumes when creating Task Definitions? Containers need CPU and Mem which makes sense. But why does Task Definitions need that?

I understood it as the name implies its just a task but now I'm wondering what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your task definition can contain **multiple** containers. So task-level CPU and memory are **hard limits** on the cumulative usage of the containers in the task.

For EC2 type tasks, the task-level CPU and memory are optional. In contrast, for Fargate they are **required**, and used by Fargate to provision resources for you that would be sufficient to run the task and all its containers.